# Issue with maxmind dependency

Tags: maxmind, jackson-databind

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:xxx:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.maxmind.db:maxmind-db:jar:1.2.1 -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.fasterxml:oss-parent:pom:28 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: This should be fixed in the 1.2.2 release of `maxmind-db`, which the 2.8.1 release of `geoip2` depends on.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by excluding the jackon dependency from maxmind

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.db</groupId>
        <artifactId>maxmind-db</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who depend on geoip2 java api:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be work for those who depend on geoip2 java api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to change to 2.8.1 and add the below. For now version 2.8.1 is not published in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.maxmind.geoip2/geoip2. So "httpclient" dependency may go away in a day or so..

There is also a discussion https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/issues/85

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```